# Migrating to Azure Resource Manager does not retroactively encrypt old data

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

We have migrated our Azure Classic storage accounts to Azure Resource Manager storage accounts. We migrated just under a week ago and data which wasn't encrypted before is still not encrypted.

We were under the impression that after migrating there would be a background task which would go through and encrypt any data in the storage account which was not already encrypted.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Data stored in the storage account prior to enabling the Storage Service Encryption will retroactively get encrypted. The data may not be immediately encrypted but the system background encryption process will encrypt the data, and it may take months for the process to encrypt the data.